# How do I multiply colors in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have an image which is a white background with a black logo.

The edges of the logo have a range of colors between black and white:

[image]

If I want to change the foreground color to green, how do I do it so that the edges are also a blend of green, based on how much black is in each pixel.

This is what I have:

[image]

If I also want to change the background color, for example to black, then how do I make each edge pixel somewhere between green and black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use *Colors > Color to Alpha*.  This will make the white pixels transparent, and the grey pixels semi-transparent.

Then you could engage the Lock Alpha Channel option on that layer (in the Layers panel), and fill it with any colour you want using *Edit > Fill with ...*. For the background create a new layer underneath, and fill with any colour you want.

For example:

[image]

Comment: For the background you can also bucket-fill in `Behind` mode (after resetting the alpha-lock of course)